# Qt, drawing charts and mouse tracking

Tags: c++, qt, drawing, elf

I must in my project display structure of ELF binary files. I use C++ and Qt Creator for making application's GUI. One of requirements is display inner structure of ELF file graphically. Like this:

[image]

I am trying use `QGraphicView` for drawing rectangles, which should represent single blocks of ELF file. It isn't big problem. Problem is, that I need after mouse click display content of selected block. I use `QMouseEvent`, more specificly Mouse Release event.

- Problem 1 - When I set MouseEvent on graphicView, I can't display anything on it.
- Problem 2 - When I use another object (now `QLabel`) for mouse tracking and place it to front of graphicView, I am able to track mouse an drawing rectangles on graphicView. But I can't group together Label and graphic view, so when user resize window of application, these two object don't change their size and stay small. And when I add these objects to layout, Label can't be in front of graphic view but is next to graphic view.

Have somebody here better idea? Like another object for drawing shapes and tracking mouse, when click on it or some variant with buttons (but I need connect some of blocks with lines) or is possible group two object to one?

Comment: Unless it is too late to change approach, I would suggest to for QML instead, it will be significantly easier and to implement the graphics and input handling. 

Also, you should go for a `QAbstractListModel` for the data representation, with the tree being represented as a list of lists, then you can use standard elements like `Repeater` or `ListView` to layout the whole thing automatically.

Comment: Thanks, QML looks pretty good. I don't have any experiences with QML, is better create whole app in QML. or is way how to integrate QML into Qt application into some object (element).

Comment: There are many ways to integrate existing C++ logic into QML: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-topic.html - that plus C++ models are directly usable in QML